# How to read the docstring present inside __init__ method of a class?

Tags: python, class, docstring

I want to read the docstring in the `__init__` method of a class:

```
class student:
def __init__(self, id, name, tier):
    '''
    :param id: id of the student
    :param name: name of the student
    :param tier: tier of the student
    '''
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.tier = tier


stu = student(7654, 'Sandeep', 12)
print(stu.__doc__)
```

If you execute the above script, the output will be 'None'.

It is possible to read the docstring of any other method of a class. But how can we also read the docstring of the `__init__` method in a class?

Comment: Well, `stu.__doc__` means the `__doc__` that belongs to the object, or failing that, the class. We want the `__doc__` that belongs to that `__init__` method instead. `stu.__init__` (alternatively, `student.__init__`, looking it up directly on the class) is that method, so...

Answer (score 2):

You should probably move the docstring up under the `class student:` line. If you want to get the `__init__` docstring, you have to use `stu.__init__.__doc__` instead of `stu.__doc__`

Comment: Yeah Thank you. I am able to read the docstring inside the __init__ method now.